# Show and hide a JavaScript snippet using a Google Tag Manager (GTM) custom event on a single page application (SPA)?

Tags: single-page-application, google-tag-manager

I am trying to setup Google Tag Manager (GTM) on my single page application (SPA).

I am pushing a custom datalayer event for each page view that looks like this:

```
window.dataLayer.push({
    event: 'customPageView',
    path: path,
    pageUrl: window.location.href,
    pageTitle: document.title,
    pageReferrer: pageReferrer,
    requiresAuth: requiresAuth,
    cid: getCid(),
  });
```

And I am using the `requiresAuth` value to conditionally show a JavaScript snippet from Zoho Desk. When the Zoho Desk JavaScript snippet is present it should display a floating help icon on the page for the user to interact with.

I only want the snippet to load on internal pages where `requiresAuth = true`. All of the login pages have `requiresAuth = false` and I do not want the snippet to load there.

Inside GTM I have a Tag that fires when the `customPageView` event has `requiresAuth = true`. Here is a screenshot of the Trigger:

[image]

When first visiting the app it seems to work fine.

The login page does not show the floating Zoho Desk icon because on that page `requiresAuth = false`.

After logging in the floating Zoho Desk icon appears because all of those pages have `requiresAuth = true`.

But then I logout and get redirected back to the login page and the Zoho Desk icon is still showing. It does not disapear until I refresh the page.

It should have disappeared as soon as I was redirected to the login page because it has `requiresAuth = false`.

How do I fix this?

When debugging with GTM Preview feature everything looks correct -  yet it still doesn't work.

Zoho Desk Tag on login page first visit:

[image]

Zoho Desk Tag on internal page visits:

[image]

Zoho Desk Tag on login page after I logout:

[image]

As you can see from the screenshots above, the tag is firing and not firing correctly. Yet I can still see the Zoho Desk icon after logging out (unless I refresh the page, then it correctly disapears).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your auth pages are also part of the SPA so there is no actual page reload before/after auth. In that case, the Zoho Desk Script/Icon will remain loaded after it was first triggered by "Custom Page View - requiresAuth = true" even if the tag does not fire again.

If you are just concerned about the visual aspect, I would recommend to create a new tag which automatically hides the icon on `requiresAuth = false` pages.

**1. HTML - Zoho Desk - Load/Show**

*Tag Logic:* Check if Zoho Desk Icon Element already exists (aka Script was already loaded), if yes: make sure it is visible (e.g. `style.display = "block"`), if no: load script

*Trigger:*  Custom Page View - requiresAuth = true

**2. HTML - Zoho Desk - Hide**

*Tag Logic:* Check if Zoho Desk Icon Element exists (aka Script was already loaded), if yes: hide it (e.g. `style.display = "none"`)

*Trigger:*  Custom Page View - requiresAuth = false